# "Tomatis"-Device implemented in Android

Tags: android, audio-processing

Is it possible on Android platform to controll the frequency output as well as the volume of the left and the right audio channels independently?

I want to make an app, which would play any mp3-music file and apply a band filter 2kHz-8kHz randomly on the left and the right channel.
Is it possible without diving into the native C programming?

P.S. The background is, There is so called Tomatis-Therapy, which claims to cure autism. It should work on the principles described above. However their devices look in a "sientific" way. I think it is a quackery and want to show our autist-parents community, that the value of such a device not higher than of an Android. At the time I'm writing this, I realise, that simply a player app with some music files early prepared on audacity would do for a prototype.

Comment: set volume http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float) and set equalization http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html Good luck! **edit:** the link for volume didn't work very well, look for the `setVolume(float, float)` method in that link.

Comment: @Budius Ok, volume seems fine, however, the equalization seems to work only for both channels. I couldn't see a channel attribute in audiofx API.